# Strange Short Stories

Tags: pattern, english, language

What’s special about each of these sentences? It's different for each sentence.

Easy:

1. A bad chef, mad like a jackal, made a damaged, half-baked milk cake a mile high.
2. Tomorrow we’ll see pretty yellow buttercups scattered across sunny green hills.
3. Your woozy son stoops to put your toy ox up onto your toy zoo.

Hard:

1. A beefy chimp hops by, almost billowy in his loopy effort.
2. A nightclub academic stayed late, off dancing with Miami DJ funk.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Easy:

> 1) All letters are in the first half of the alphabet (A-M).
>  2) Each of the words includes a doubled letter (tomoRRow, etc.)
>  3) All letters are in the second half of the alphabet (N-Z).

Hard:

> 1) The letters in each word are in alphabetical order.
>  2) The last letters of the words are A, B, C, etc.